# Why is 0x1F segment special in OSX?

Tags: macos

Some of the Mach-O executables have an LC_UNIXTHREAD command with the following initial register values:

```
cmd LC_UNIXTHREAD
    cmdsize 80
     flavor i386_THREAD_STATE
      count i386_THREAD_STATE_COUNT
        eax 0x00000000 ebx    0x00000000 ecx 0x00000000 edx 0x00000000
        edi 0x00000000 esi    0x00000000 ebp 0x00000000 esp 0x00000000
        ss  0x0000001f eflags 0x00000000 eip 0x00002788 cs  0x00000017
        ds  0x0000001f es     0x0000001f fs  0x00000000 gs  0x00000000
```

The **eip** is set to the entry point of the app, but for some reason the rest also have a special initial value. (If they are all zeroes, the application crashes randomly because some of the malloc() does not return with clean memory area.)
Any idea about the mysterious 0x1F segment?

Comment: It may just be garbage. Why do you wanna know?

Comment: because I need to wrap applications with a launcher and before calling the "real" entry point specified by the eip here I need to create an environment as if the wrapper application would not exist.

Comment: Maybe 1F is the segment assigned to your app's working storage.  You wouldn't want it dumping on segment zero where all the system stuff is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a deeper look I finally found the reason:
depending on the selected base SDK and deployment target, GCC uses different system libraries and common runtime library object (crt1.o)

```
SDK10.4, Target10.4: /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk/usr/lib/crt1.o
SDK10.5, Target10.4: /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/usr/lib/crt1.o
SDK10.5, Target10.5: /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/usr/lib/crt1.10.5.o
SDK10.6, Target10.4: /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/lib/crt1.o
SDK10.6, Target10.5: /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/lib/crt1.10.5.o
SDK10.6, Target10.6: /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/lib/crt1.10.6.o
```

These object files contain the initial UNIX thread load command with the mentioned register states. If the selected SDK and the deployment target are both 10.4 (first line) then the CS,DS,ES,SS will differ from 0.

Answer (score 1):

What's mysterious about it? You kinda need valid selectors for CS,DS,SS :)

```
selector 0x17: RPL3, LDT, descriptor index 0x10
selector 0x1F: RPL3, LDT, descriptor index 0x18
```

Windows (at least win7-32bit) uses the following two:

```
CODE: 0x1B - RPL3, GDT, descriptor index 0x10
DATA: 0x23 - RPL3, GDT, descriptor index 0x20
```

Comment: 90% of my apps has zeroes everywhere (except the eip obviously). What selectors do they use if you do not specify any?

Comment: That I don't know - try examining descriptor base+size (as well as register contents for "normal" threads) in a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

CS needs to be set to a selector that has the X flag on.
DS, ES are data segments and therefore point onto a different selector.
FS, GS are also different. I'm not sure about Mac OS but on Windows those two are used for very specific things:

Win32: FS is used to store information about the process (FS:[30] = PEB, FS:[0] = SEH Info)
Win64: GS is used instead of FS, rest is more or less the same.

On some applications in Mac OS X you will see that GS has a value of 0x0F and FS is set to zero, chances are that GS:[XXX] contains informations regarding the process.